# Updated json not updating the jstree

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jstree

I am trying to use jstree in my ruby on rails application. I have the following data captured in rails
**TransferRequestController.rb**

```
def sources
    @disease_code_id = params[:disease_code_id]
    @phase_name = params[:phase_id]
    @phase_id = RecruitmentPhase.select('recruitment_phases.phase_id').where('recruitment_phases.phase_name = ?', @phase_name)
    #byebug
    @sources = QuestionnaireItem.joins('join traits on traits.trait_id = questionnaire_items.trait_id join trait_groups on trait_groups.trait_id = traits.trait_id join sources on sources.source_id = traits.source_id join disease_phaseid_questionnaires on disease_phaseid_questionnaires.questionnaire_id = questionnaire_items.questionnaire_id join recruitment_phases on disease_phaseid_questionnaires.phase_id = recruitment_phases.phase_id').where('disease_phaseid_questionnaires.disease_code_id = ? and disease_phaseid_questionnaires.phase_id = ?', @disease_code_id, @phase_id.first.phase_id).where.not(:recruitment_phases => {phase_name:nil}).select('distinct sources.source_name', 'sources.source_id', 'recruitment_phases.phase_name', 'recruitment_phases.phase_id')
    @sources.each { |x| $data.push(Node.new(x.source_name.strip, @phase_name.chomp, x.source_name.strip))}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render json: $data.flatten}
    end
  end
```

In my application.js

```
function nextCall(phase_id, disease_code_id){

    $.ajax({
        url: "source/"+phase_id+"/"+disease_code_id,
        dataType:'json',
        type:'GET',
        data: "{}",

        success: function (data) {
            $('#using_json_2').jstree(true).settings.core.data = data;
            $('#using_json_2').jstree('refresh');
        }
    });
}
```

While debugging it, I am perfectly getting the node structure for the data as shown below

```
[
    0,
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 4",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 4"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 3",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 2",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "Baseline",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Baseline"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 3 extra",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 3 extra"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 1",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "question form popgen",
        "parent": "Baseline",
        "text": "question form popgen"
    },
    {
        "id": "administrative/derived popgen",
        "parent": "Baseline",
        "text": "administrative/derived popgen"
    },
    {
        "id": "practitioner record",
        "parent": "Baseline",
        "text": "practitioner record"
    }
]
```

But my tree structure looks like the following
[jstree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAUL4.png)

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I've never used that library, but what about changing the ids to something with lowercase and without spaces or special characters? Are you getting any error in the browser console? Also, what about returning the json ready for jstree with `{'core' : { 'data' : yourCurrentJsonArray}}`, so you just call `$('#using_json_2').jstree(data);`? At least that's the way I can see it's used [in the docs](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/).

Comment: I tried changing the IDs to lower case and removing the special characters. Unfortunately, I am getting in to infinite loop with the event mentioned in the APIs of Jstree i.e selected_node.jstree. Can you please help me out, I am going nuts over this issue

Answer (score 0):

It's because of that first `0` you had in your json. Remove it and it will work as expected.

```js
$('#tree').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 4",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 4"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 3",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 2",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "Baseline",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Baseline"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 3 extra",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 3 extra"
    },
    {
        "id": "Follow-up 1",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "Follow-up 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "question form popgen",
        "parent": "Baseline",
        "text": "question form popgen"
    },
    {
        "id": "administrative/derived popgen",
        "parent": "Baseline",
        "text": "administrative/derived popgen"
    },
    {
        "id": "practitioner record",
        "parent": "Baseline",
        "text": "practitioner record"
    }
]
} });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.12/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.12/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id='tree'>
```